# Prepared statements and floats

Tags: php, google-maps, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am playing with my own implementation of [Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) and I want to do it properly through prepared statements and mysqli object (not mysql as stated in the linked example) Also, I added "own registration" so I am afraid of SQL Injection. But, how do I bind Float value to the prepared statement?

My table has (among others) `FLOAT` type columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,  
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

But reading the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) I can see only these types:

```
Character   Description
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Should I assume that when column is a `FLOAT` i should use `b` for a blob? (because its not string and not a double value). And the same for `TEXT` type column?

Comment: and in that case is string a text?

Comment: In PHP, double is just another name for float.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

At C level they all are stored as double, and the real size of the type depends on the platform.

Comment: Ok, so I should assume that using blob is for ... well, blob? :) Makes my life easier :)

Comment: Have you tried to change the column type of lat, lng in database to DOUBLE? the prepared statement with "d" worked perfect for me

Comment: I did not, but changing the prepared statement to "d" solved the problem

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just use "d" for non integer numbers